# $_FILES is empty

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I am using [Ajax file upload](http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/ajax-multiple-file-upload-form-using-jquery/)
bt $_FILES is always empty .

this is my php page

```
    include('../../inc/functions.php');
    $allowdExt = array("mp4","flv");
    $uploaddir = '../../uploads/videos/';
    $filename = basename($_FILES['uploadv']['name']);
    echo "file: $uploaddir".$filename ;
    exit;

        $extension = getExtension($filename);
        $extension = strtolower($extension);

        if(!in_array($extension,$allowdExt)){
            $errors =1;
        }
        else
        {
            $file_name = MakeRandomChars().'.'.$extension ;
            $newname=$uploaddir.$file_name;
            $copied = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadv']['tmp_name'], $newname);
            if (!$copied)
            {
                $errors =1;
            }
        }

        if( $errors == 1){
            echo "0";
        }else{
            echo $file_name;
        }
```

and this is my jquery code :

```
$(function(){
    var btnUpload=$('#uploadVideo');
    var status=$('#status');
    new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
        action: 'pages/upload-video.php',
        name: 'uploadv',
        onSubmit: function(file, ext){
             if (! (ext && /^(flv|mp4)$/.test(ext))){ 
                status.text('Only Flv,Mp4 files are allowed');
                return false;

            }
            $('#wait').fadeIn();
        },
        onComplete: function(file, response){
            status.text('');
            if(response != "0"){
                $('#wait').fadeOut();
                $('#videoIcon').fadeIn();
                $('#status').attr('video',response);
            }
        }
    });     
});
```

Comment: how do you know that $_FILES is empty? where's your print_r?

Answer (score 2):

With `ajaxupload` you need to get the data from the raw php input, not from the `$_FILES`

You can see the sample here: https://github.com/valums/file-uploader/blob/master/server/php.php (the `qqUploadedFileXhr` class)

Comment: thanks for your answer ,bt it worked for me $_FILES in other pages ?

Comment: @T4mer: `ajaxupload` passes the files though raw input, not `$_FILES`. Look at their readme at https://github.com/valums/file-uploader: `This plugin uses XHR for uploading multiple files with progress-bar...`